# iOS viewport - how to enable auto zoom on input

Tags: html, ios, viewport

I have a responsive site - currently the viewport it set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```

I want the users to be able to zoom, but I would still like it to automatically zoom when the user selects an input field. I used to have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

but this would zoom in automatically when the device was rotated to landscape.

Comment: Question is how do I enable auto zoom on input - the title.

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom in automatically when the device was rotated to landscape"? Isn't that a good thing because the browser is adjusting to the new window size?

Comment: I want the page to adjust with the rotation - not simply zoom in. It seems like it is because of the initial width.